# ¿Cómo puedo controlar el error "System.Net.WebException" en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Su funcionalidad de mi aplicación es descargar vídeos de Youtube, algunos vídeos se descarga sin ningún problema pero en otros no y me muestra un error.

Como puedo controlar o hacer que muestre un mensaje para que mi aplicación no se cierre, el error es el siguiente:

> Se produjo la excepción System.Net.WebException. HResult=0x80131509 Mensaje = Error en el servidor remoto: (403) Prohibido.

El problema se presenta en la siguiente línea de código:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
            thread.Start();
```

Este es el código completo del botón descargar:

```
private void btnDescargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ProgressBarDownload.Minimum = 0;
            ProgressBarDownload.Maximum = 100;
            IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(txtURL.Text);
            VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(cboResolution.Text));
            if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
            VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Downloads\\", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));
            downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
            thread.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturar excepciones en un thread diferente o en un método asíncrono tiene sus dificultades. En este caso, el problema probablemente es que intentas capturar la excepción **fuera del hilo en el que se produce**, lo que no es posible.

En tu caso la solución probablemente sea un `try/catch` dentro del propio hilo:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
       () => { 
               try 
               {
                   downloader.Execute();
               } 
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                   //gestionar la excepción. 
               }) 
             { IsBackground = true };
```

De todas maneras,como no me canso de repetir, no se debe usar la clase `Thread`, ya que es difícil de manejar incluso para gente experta y tenemos en .Net clases mas modernas y sencillas de manejar como `BackGroundWorker` o `Task`.

Aqui te dejo un enlace a una solución usando `Task`: [Catching exceptions caused in different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17298673/579895)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pikoh, si me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando el try chatch, debes incluir la librería
 using System.Windows.Forms;

```
try {

       Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { 
       IsBackground = true };
       thread.Start();

    }catch (Exception e){

                           MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                         }
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté y me apareciendo el error nuevamente.

Comment: @JhonH. como complemento de la respuesta de marco de igual forma sugiero que revises el `InnerException` con `e.InnerException`, ahí te puede dar más detalle de la falla presentada